# Django / Python calendar module

Tags: python, django, calendar

I want to add a link to a calendar, so every single day will have a link to the day page, as you can see from the urls.py every link is already generate dynamically.

When in html you show the HTMLCalendar {{ cal | safe }}  you can see the days, but how can i add a link to every single day?
I've been trying a for loop with no success for the last two days.
Happy to buy a box of beer to anybody who will help me

```js
from django.urls import path
from dayplanner import views

app_name = 'dayplanner'

urlpatterns = [
    #Day Planner Home Page
    path('', views.dayplanner, name='dayplanner'),
    path('<int:year>/<str:month>/<int:day>', views.dayplanner, name='dayplanner'),

]
```

```css
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block content %}



<div style="max-width: 500px; margin-left: 20%;">
{{ cal | safe }}
</div>
   
    
 
  
  




{% endblock %}
```

```html
from django.shortcuts import render
import calendar
from calendar import HTMLCalendar
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import datetime as date



def dayplanner(request, year=datetime.now().year, month=datetime.now().strftime('%B'), day=datetime.now().strftime('%A')):    
    
    # Capitalize the title
    month = month.title()
    
    # Shows the month number
    month_number = list(calendar.month_name).index(month)

    # This is the Calendar object
    cal = HTMLCalendar().formatmonth(year, month_number)

    # Generate links to each day in the calendar
    day_links = ''
    for day_number in range(1, calendar.monthrange(year, month_number)[1] + 1):
        day_links += f'<a href="/{year}/{month}/{day_number}/">{day_number}</a> '

    # Shows the current date
    now = datetime.now()

    
    return render(request, 'home.html', {
        "cal":cal,
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you should create your own calendar which inherits from `HTMLCalendar`

```
from calendar import HTMLCalendar


class CustomHTMLCalendar(HTMLCalendar):
    def formatday(self, day, weekday):
        """
        Return a day as a table cell.
        """
        if day == 0:
            # day outside month
            return '<td class="%s">&nbsp;</td>' % self.cssclass_noday
        else:
            return f'<td class="{self.cssclasses[weekday]}">{self._get_day_link(self._year, self._month, day)}</td>'

    def formatmonth(self, theyear: int, themonth: int, withyear: bool = ...) -> str:
        self._year = theyear
        self._month = themonth
        return super().formatmonth(theyear, themonth, withyear)

    def _get_day_link(self, year, month, day_number):
        return f'<a href="/{year}/{month}/{day_number}/">{day_number}</a> '
```

and then in your views

```
cal = CustomHTMLCalendar().formatmonth(year, month_number)
```